# How can one determine whether two given Hamiltonians are supersymmetric partners?

Tags: supersymmetry, hamiltonian, differential-equations

Given two Hamiltonians in a general form of second order differential equations, how do I find out if they are SUSY partners or not? Given the factorisation of a Hamiltonian in the form of $a^\dagger a$, one can construct a SUSY partner by evaluating $aa^\dagger$, right?

My question is, given two hamiltonians in differential equation form, where this factorization is not explicit or immediately noticeable, how can one proceed to verify if they are indeed SUSY partners?

Answer (score 0):

You could get an idea if the spectra are the same with the possible exception of the ground state. That would require a lot of work to diagonalize theoretically but is more experimental. That is a first check. You then have to find find an $a$ that annihilates the ground state. Then get a factorization of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: So I would actually have to solve the two systems! Either that, or attempt direct factorization? Is there no simpler mathematical check?